# The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I cannot create a new project in VS Community 2015 because of this error. The project I am trying to make is a PowerPoint Web App Content Add-in. I've Googled this error extensively and have tried the following, to no avail:

1. Uninstalling and reinstalling NuGet
2. Repair-install of Visual Studio
3. Uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio

Does anyone know what else can be done to try to solve this issue? I am running VS on a Windows 8 virtual machine (Virtual Box) on a Mac, although I don't think this should cause any problems.

Comment: This may be a strange idea... but have you opened Visual Studio "As Administrator"?

The first time I ran Visual Studio I was getting a similar error... I just ran it as administrator and bingo!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually restarted the VS again, and that worked